# Um produto referenciar vários tamanhos no banco de dados. Como fazer?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, tabela-html, relacionamento

Olá!

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema em Java com PostgreSQL, e agora cheguei numa etapa que estou com uma grande dificuldade. Tenho três tabelas que precisam se relacionar, são elas:

Produto: codigo, descricao, preço

Unidade: codigo, nome

Estoque: produto, unidade, quantidade

O problema está no estoque, pois eu gostaria de inserir, por exemplo, 30 produtos em estoque do Produto A. Se eu não usasse unidades, seria bem fácil, pois seria apenas inseri-los em estoque e tava feito. O problema é que eu tenho que colocar esta quantidade nas unidades, por exemplo: Produto A recebe 30 quantidades, sendo 10 na unidade P, 10 na unidade M, 5 na unidade G e 5 na unidade GG.

Como posso resolver isto?

Obrigado!

Comment: Essencialmente é o que tem neste pergunta, claro que precisa adaptar à sia necessidade, mas a pergunta não não foi específica mesmo. Emfim, tem que ter cada SKU como um produto diferente. Se tiver dúvidas mais específicas depois de começar modelar, pode fazer perguntas específicas.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, já alterei o título. A pergunta sugerida de resposta não corresponde ao meu problema.